# Step response of power load switches

Tags: power, load, slew-rate

Many load switches implement a fix or controlled slew-rate of its output current in order to prevent inrush currents.

I was wondering what is the step response of this kind of switches after the slew-rate time. To be exact, if I use such a switch to charge 200uF capacitors and my circuit draw some energy from those capacitors (not fully discharged, just a little dip), will the switch re-charge the capacitors instantly or will they be charged smoothly due to slew-rate time?

Comment: It cannot be instant but limited by I, low ESR of cap, RdsOn of switch and energy available (Power*time) and soak time at voltage max. This can easily vary from seconds to minutes.

Comment: So, the slew-rate doesn't matter and the maximum allowed current would be flow throught the load switch.

Comment: fastest slew rate is limited by cap specs , ESR*C=T and dv/dt =Ic/C

Comment: So, once the load switch is enabled and Vout reaches its maximum value, the response would be same as it would with a conventional high side switch (P-channel mosfet).

Comment: essential same but with some memory effects.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about which switch you are talking about. Different switches might behave differently.

Comment: I was studing the SiP32508 of Vishay

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the Vishay SiP32508 high-side switch is that if the voltage on both ends of the IC doesn't droop below 1 - 1.1 V, then the slew control circuitry won't engage, and the IC will behave as a 44-mOhm Rds(on) transistor switch.